# Getting multipage images from qlmanage

Tags: quicklook

qlmanage can produce PNG's. Like this https://superuser.com/a/162221

But using the standard command I only get page 1.
Is it possible to get page 2? I was wondering if I could mimic the quicklook function in Apple Wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qlmanage` is really not meant as a tool for any production project. It's a debugging tool. It runs with different privileges as the normal quicklook, does not provide the same level of security. And moreover it's *REALLY* not meant to be used server side.

That said, to answer your question: no, when `qlmanage` produces PNGs, it's invoking generators' thumbnailing code which is not meant to page through the document.

The Quick Look function in Apple Wiki is using a specific client that is able to:

1. request the preview (and not thumbnails) from a limited set of generators
2. interpret the preview
3. produces images for each page of the preview when it makes sense

There is no public API to do that yourself, alas.